# Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.eslintno-unused-expressions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

Hi I am using a ternary operator inside a function. But eslint throws error on this. Pls help me to fix this.

```
  const Test = (showBtn, bubbleId, latitude, longitude, zoom, drillLevel) => {
    setShowBtn(showBtn);
    drillLevel === 'area' ? getCitiesData(bubbleId) : getStatesData();
    setViewport({
      ...viewport,
      latitude,
      longitude,
      zoom,
    });
  };
```

Comment: eslint also shows line and column, can you update question with more details?

Comment: it throws error on the drillLevel line

Comment: Then check this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/61287706/1737158

Answer (score 6):

If your current code works, it would probably be more appropriate to avoid the conditional operator entirely and use `if`/`else` instead:

```
if (drillLevel === 'area') getCitiesData(bubbleId)
else getStatesData();
```

This way, you don't actually have any unused expressions, which is the *right* way to fix this sort of linter warning.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add this [`allowTernary`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-expressions#allowternary) comment above the ternary operator expression, to disable eslint error for that line:

```
/*eslint no-unused-expressions: ["error", { "allowTernary": true }]*/
drillLevel === 'area' ? getCitiesData(bubbleId) : getStatesData();
```

Comment: do we need to do this everytime? or  is there a permanent config for this in `eslintrc`?

Answer (score 1):

May be you forget to assign get* result to some variable, waht about `viewport`?

```js
const data = drillLevel === 'area' ?
  getCitiesData(bubbleId) :
  getStatesData();
```

Answer (score 1):

https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-expressions

add option to your eslint to `allowTernary = true`

You can add it as a comment above the line or in eslint config where you have your rules defined

`/*eslint no-unused-expressions: ["error", { "allowTernary": true }]*/`

[image]