# React Components conditional rendering, problems with tertiary operator in a handle click function rendering wrong component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm a new developer and this is my first question on stack overflow so please be patient. I hope this is the right community and the correct way to ask a question (let me know if there are ways I can imporve my inquiries).

So I have a React functional compoenent that renders three forms conditionally. I took one big form and broke it into three sections so that when the user clicks the next button in the div, they are taken to the next form and the next button calls a click handler function that uses state to determine which form should be shown with a tertiary operator to check the state. My problem is that the logic of the handler function shows the third form after first click instead of the second as I would expect, any idea of a simpler work around or how to fix this? I have the code below and simplified it as much as I could to try and just show the logic issue I'm dealing with.

//Code

```
import { useState } from "react";   


export default function PinFormTest(){

    const [showFirstForm, setShowFirstForm] = useState(true)
    const [showSecondForm, setShowSecondForm] = useState(false)
    const [showThirdForm, setShowThirdForm] = useState(false)

    const handleNextForm = () => {
         showFirstForm ? setShowFirstForm(false) && setShowSecondForm(true):
            showSecondForm ? setShowSecondForm(false) && setShowThirdForm(true):
                console.log("error")

    }

    return(
      <>
        <div className="formContainer">
          {showFirstForm ? 
            (<>firstForm</>): showSecondForm ? (<>secondForm</>): (<>thirdForm</>)
          }
        </div>
        <div>
          <button onClick={() => handlePreviousForm()}>Previous</button>
          <button onClick={() => handleNextForm()}>Next</button>
        </div>
      </>)
}
```

Comment: The way the `&&` operator works is that it will only evaluate the expression on the right-hand side if the expression on the left-hand side evaluates to something *truthy*. `setShowFirstForm(false)` doesn't return anything, in other words it's *falsy*, which means that `setShowSecondForm(true)` never runs. BTW, the conditional operator you're using is called a **ternary**, not "tertiary"

Comment: you sir are a legend, thank you for the explanation I've spent two days on this with no luck. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In such situations try to avoid using the ternary operator because it will cause issues like readability, which makes it harder to debug later on.

```
const handleNextForm = () => {
    if (showFirstForm) {
      setShowFirstForm(false);
      setShowSecondForm(true);
      return;
    }

    if (showSecondForm) {
      setShowSecondForm(false);
      setShowThirdForm(true);
      return;
    }
    console.log("error");
  };
```

Comment: thanks! this looks cleaner than what I'm using and appreciate the alternative code example

Answer (score 0):

You should write multiple lines of statements in ternary operators by writing comma separated statements. Your correct code will be;

```
  const handleNextForm = () => {
    showFirstForm
      ? (setShowFirstForm(false), setShowSecondForm(true))
      : showSecondForm
      ? (setShowSecondForm(false), setShowThirdForm(true))
      : console.error(error);
  };
```

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate the code example with ternary.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `&&` and it will only evaluate `right` only if the `left` is `true`

> `left` && `right`   // Example

So you are using `setShowFirstForm(false) && setShowSecondForm(true)` so this will first evaluate `setShowFirstForm(false)` from which you are not returning anything so the return value will be `undefined` which is a `falsy` value. So this will evaluate `setShowSecondForm(true)`

**`Solution 1`**

You can use `,` here as: [Codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-snowflake-d4gt0y?file=/src/App.js)

```
showFirstForm
  ? (setShowFirstForm(false), setShowSecondForm(true))
  : showSecondForm
  ? (setShowSecondForm(false), setShowThirdForm(true))
  : console.log("error");
```

**`Solution 2`**

You can use simple `if-else` branching, [Codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-voice-ymzljc?file=/src/App.js)

```
if (showFirstForm) {
  setShowFirstForm(false);
  setShowSecondForm(true);
} else if (showSecondForm) {
  setShowSecondForm(false);
  setShowThirdForm(true);
} else {
  console.log("error");
}
```

**`Solution 3`**

You can use `Map` here to create a map for form level and the component to render, other solution won't be a better solution if the stages in form increases. [Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-banach-w7tuub?file=/src/App.js)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import FirstForm from "./components/FirstForm";
import SecondForm from "./components/SecondForm";
import ThirdForm from "./components/ThirdForm";

const formComponentsArr = [FirstForm, SecondForm, ThirdForm];
const formComponents = new Map(
  formComponentsArr.map((comp, i) => {
    return [i + 1, comp];
  })
);

export default function App() {
  const [level, setLevel] = useState(1);

  function handleNextForm() {
    if (level !== formComponents.size) {
      setLevel((l) => l + 1);
    }
  }

  function getComponent() {
    const comp = formComponents.get(level);
    return comp ? comp() : null;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="formContainer">{getComponent()}</div>
      <div>
        {/* <button onClick={() => handlePreviousForm()}>Previous</button> */}
        <button onClick={() => handleNextForm()}>Next</button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

**`Solution 4 - BEST SULUTION`**

Create a custom hook as which will handle the `next` and `previous`. All you have to do is to pass an array of components that needs to be rendered sequentially. [Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-brook-qlj9m5?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thank you! was able to get it to work with the first solution. VS Code was giving me the error "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression. eslint(no-unused-expressions)" I fixed the issue by adding "// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-expressions" above the code block. This is the first time I've had to do this, would you be able to explain what's happening and why eslint has a problem with this?

Comment: @Aleph-Naught You can read in [docs](https://eslint.org/docs/2.0.0/rules/no-unused-expressions)

Comment: Please read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61287650/expected-an-assignment-or-function-call-and-instead-saw-an-expression-eslintno-u). You can get the idea

Comment: @Aleph-Naught I've added 2 solution more. Have a look

Comment: Thank you for the resources! I would give you the upvote if I could but my account is still too new. Keep being awesome!

Comment: @Aleph-Naught It helps you that's enough. then Upvote doesn't matter.